# In my project i have two apps , beacon_info and offers, i need to use the store as a foreign key from my beacon_info app to offers

Tags: python, django-1.7

**Beacon_info apps models**
The code shown below is the one havinng the field to which i want to make as a foreign key in another app as discssed below.

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.encoding import smart_unicode
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import datetime

    class store(models.Model):
            store_name = models.CharField('Store Name',max_length=100)
            store_id = models.CharField('Store_ID', max_length=20, unique=True)
            store_email = models.EmailField('Email_ID', max_length=254)
            address = models.CharField('Address', max_length=250)
            country = models.CharField('Country', max_length=50)
            state = models.CharField('State', max_length=50)
            city = models.CharField('City',max_length=50)
            pincode = models.CharField('Pincode', max_length=15)
            contact_no = models.CharField('Contact', max_length=15)
            createdat = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
            def __unicode__(self):
                return smart_unicode(self.id)
```

**Offers app's models**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.encoding import smart_unicode
from beacon_info.models import *
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import datetime
class offer(models.Model):
    offer_code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    store_code = models.ForeignKey('beacon_info.models.store')
    entry_exit_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    offername = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    membership = models.CharField(max_length=5, default=1)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()
    createdat =models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return smart_unicode(self.offername)
```

Comment: You didn't really ask a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
models.ForeignKey('beacon_info.models.store')
```

should be

```
models.ForeignKey('beacon_info.store')
```

the convention is to use `app_name.model_name`, there is no need to include `models` in that.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey

> To refer to models defined in another application, you can explicitly
>   specify a model with the full application label. For example, if the
>   `Manufacturer` model above is defined in another application called
>   `production`, you’d need to use:
>
> ```
> class Car(models.Model):
>      manufacturer = models.ForeignKey('production.Manufacturer')
> ```